FPGA->PC data transmission over commodity networking hardware
I asked this question over on Network Engineering, but apparently it's mostly off-topic there, so hoping this might be a better location.
We have a set of physical hardware that comprises a collection of up to 8 modules, each of which is a SoC combining an FPGA and an ARM core running Linux. Currently, all of these modules are connected to a single PC over ethernet, and on the module, all the communication is handled using the normal TCP/IP stack in Linux, with data from the FPGA being routed through the software layer.
This system works well and is reliable, and having the system use normal networking protocols and standards has proven to have real benefits. The problem with the current system is that we are producing data from the FPGA at a much higher data rate than can be handled by the processor (both because the processor is not fast enough, and because the ethernet hardware is 1Gb/s).
We are proposing to have a second data stream from the FPGA which is passed over a dedicated SFP+ optical link. Obviously, there are many ways in which this could be implemented. Our current thinking is, at the FPGA level, we simply pack the data in ethernet frames and fire it out over the optical link at 10Gb/s. Each module's optical link is then plugged into one of the 8 lanes available on a dual QSFP+ commodity networking card.
Flow control is then handled either at the ethernet layer (with e.g. pause frames or PFC) or over the existing software TCP link at the application layer. I.e. only sending any data if the QSFP+ NIC has sufficient space in its buffers.
We can detect loss of data, but we would hope this would happen vanishingly rarely.
The question then is what the pitfalls of such an architecture might be.
Are ethernet frames passed one-per-link in the case of QSFP+ (i.e. each frame is not striped across the 4 links), so each of the 4 QSFP+ links can be driven from a different module?
Can I easily receive the raw ethernet frames on the receiving side, under either Linux or Windows?
Are certain bits/manufacturers of kit better for this kind of thing? How ubiquitous is support for PFC?
